# Why is $x^\alpha-\alpha x\le 1-\alpha$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I was reading the Proof of Hölder's Inequality in Measure Theory, and i saw, that our professor used an inequality and didn't explain, why it is true, and the inequality is;

> For $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $x\in\mathbb R_+$
>
> $x^\alpha-\alpha x\le 1-\alpha$

$\textbf{I tried ;}$

$x^\alpha-\alpha x\le 1-\alpha$

$\Leftrightarrow x^\alpha\le 1-\alpha+\alpha x=1+\alpha(x-1)$

and $x^\alpha\le 1+\alpha(x-1)$ looks similar to bernoulli inequality, if you take $x'=\alpha(x-1)$ and $r=\frac{1}{\alpha}$

$(1+x')^r\ge x$

Is my justification correct, and does Bernoulli hold also for rational exponents ?

Comment: Looking at your username, another way to prove it jumps out. Given $\alpha$, let $f(x) = x^\alpha - \alpha x$. Differentiate.

Comment: This is the third-fourth time this exercise from one-before-the-last exercise in Tel Aviv's University Calculus I's 12-th exercise has popped up...

Comment: @DanielFischer but differentiating is useful if $x\ge 1$, or not ?

Comment: Differentiating is _always_ useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without words...almost:

$$f(x):=x^\alpha-\alpha x\implies f'(x)=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}-\alpha=0\iff x=1 .$$

$$f''(1)=\alpha(\alpha-1)<0\implies x=1\;\;\text{maximum point's abscissa}\implies$$

$$\forall\,x\in\Bbb R^+\setminus\{1\}\;,\;\;x^{\alpha}-\alpha x=f(x)\le f(1)=1-\alpha$$

Comment: ah ok with the 2nd derivative.